# How to keep PHPUnit tests internal, without external communication?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

Is it possible to ensure that no tests communicate with an external source? While I think all of my tests take care of mocking out any external dependencies, I'd like to know if there is any sort of catch all to ensure my test suite does not have any unintended communication with third party APIs et cetera.

Comment: how do you communicate with external source? If you wrap it with guzzle (an HTTP Client library) you can mock easily (let me know if you need some help).

Comment: There are many things that end up communicating through events/listeners/jobs, sockets, apns pushes, aws and third party APIs. While I've mocked out everything that I think is necessary in base test case, as I mentioned above I'm inquiring if there is any sort of catch-all ensuring no outside communication during tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is tagged as Laravel, I'm going to assume that you'd prefer an answer based on Laravel.

Assuming that you're not testing communication with an external API (which is worth doing at some point), you're going to want to approach it in the same way that you approach anything else.

Mocking.

Both your models and your API library are communicating with a data source. To test your models you mock them, so that you aren't interacting with the database. You need to do the same for your API, mock the class that returns the result, or skip it entirely and throw in an example response.

It all depends entirely on what you are testing. If you don't wish to test how you handle data from the API, simply don't call anything that interacts with the API.

Comment: I am mocking everything as far as I know, I'm not sure if I can clarify my question but I'm more looking for a backup to ensure there is nothing missed.

Comment: There is no backup, you just need to check through your code. Short of removing the connection to the outside world on the server, there's nothing really to be done.

Comment: I figured as much and everything seems well mocked I just thought it was worth checking.

Comment: http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html